# Is it possible to bring internal frames in javafx similar to swing

Tags: javafx

I am new to Javafx , and how can we bring internal frames in Javafx similar to swing in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, JavaFX has a SwingNode control that supports Swing controls.